# RtlCheckSandboxedToken

Tags: windows, sandbox, vms

Does anyone know what is the purpose of `RtlCheckSandboxedToken()` in ntdll.dll,
i cannot find any documentation,
its prototype is:

```
 
NTSYSAPI
NTSTATUS
NTAPI
RtlCheckSandboxedToken(
    _In_opt_ HANDLE TokenHandle,
    _Out_ PBOOLEAN IsSandboxed
    );
```

source: https://github.com/processhacker/processhacker/blob/master/phnt/include/ntrtl.h

Is it something like `IsDebuggerPresent()` for VMs?

Comment: Without knowing anything further about this function, I'd surmise purely based on its name alone, that it has to do with the sandboxing mechanism of Windows Store apps. Oh and the handle you pass is very likely any plain old [access token](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/secauthz/access-tokens).

Answer (score 1):

The following call stack can be found in `MrmCoreR.dll`:

```
Microsoft::Resources::MetroAppClientProfile::IsUnsafeLoadPriFileAllowed
Microsoft::Resources::HasCapability
RtlCheckSandboxedToken
```

Seems like it's used by Metro applications to know if they were run in the sandbox. And `RtlCheckSandboxedToken()` checks the token if it can be accessed via some specific security descriptor to determine if it's sandboxed.