# How to get the call stack of WinAPI functions?

Tags: windows, debugging, static-analysis, dynamic-analysis, winapi

Yesterday, I noticed an [answer](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/19238/40872) to a question about the purpose of a certain undocumented function, which is a call stack (including the DLL library) for this function, This got me interested in the approachs in this matter!

How to get the WinAPI function's **call stack** and which **DLL libraries** that have the function there ? and is there a way to find out all of that **statically** without the debugger ?